# Sample Multiple Raster Layers Python QGIS 3.26.1

Tags: raster, pyqgis, spatial-query, sampling

I would like to Identify the value of 15 tiff files at the same coordinates. I am currently using an external python script which iterates through each file. How would I do this with the QGIS Python API without iterating through a list of the files?

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=col_val)
for j, layer_path in enumerate(layer_paths):
    values = [0.0] * len(x_coords)
    for i in range(len(x_coords)):
        layer = QgsRasterLayer(layer_path)
        values[i] = layer.dataProvider().sample(QgsPointXY(x_coord[i], y_coord[i]), 1)[0]
    df[col_val[j]] = values
```

Comment: You have 15 different files. Ultimately, you need to iterate through something related to the files. Alternatively, you can add the files to QGIS and iterate through the raster layers.

Answer (score 0):

The following script is taking all tiff files from a folder and excel file having coordinates list using GDAL and ogr

```
for filename in os.listdir(directory ):

 if filename.endswith(".tif"):
    loc=os.path.join(directory,filename)        
    src_ds=gdal.Open(loc)
    gt=src_ds.GetGeoTransform()
    rb=src_ds.GetRasterBand(1)
    lst=[]

    for i in range(len(main_DF)) :
            long=main_DF.loc[i, "Latitude"]# reading from excel
            lat=main_DF.loc[i, "Longitude"]

            px = int((lat - gt[0]) / gt[1])
            py = int((long - gt[3]) / gt[5])

            intval=rb.ReadAsArray(px,py,1,1)#pixel location of geospatial coordinates

            lst.append(intval[0])

    main_DF[filename]=lst
```